# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre «champiñón» y «seta»?

Tags: vocabulario

Según RAE, *seta* es:

> Cualquier especie de hongo, comestible o no, con forma de sombrilla, sostenida por un pedicelo.

y *champiñón* es:

> Nombre común a varias especies de hongos agaricáceos, algunos de los cuales son comestibles.

Aparte de que *champiñón* es un nombre común, ¿hay otra diferencia? ¿Una palabra es más especifica que la otra? ¿Hay preferencias regionales entre las palabras?

Comment: Para mí, un champiñón siempre ha sido una seta comestible.

Comment: Siempre pensé, utilicé y lo oí como que champiñón es una especie concreta o un subconjunto de especies de setas...

Answer (score 7):

Estríctamente hablando una **seta** es el cuerpo fructífero que desarrollan algunas especies de hongos durante una etapa de su ciclo reproductivo, mientras que el **champiñón** es una *variedad de seta*, la que desarrolla el hongo comestible [Agaricus bisporus](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agaricus_bisporus) y otros muy similares.

En la práctica ambas palabras se confunden en el habla común, y eso va a depender por supuesto de la variedad de español que se hable y de si estás en un restaurante, un mercado o una facultad de agronomía.

La situación en **Chile** es la siguiente: "*Setas*" no se usa. En su lugar decimos "*Hongos*" para referirnos a todas las setas. "*Champiñones*" son las setas comestibles con forma de globo o con sombrerito (incluidos por ejemplo el muchardón y el mízcalo). "*Callampas*" son las demás setas comestibles, con formas más caprichosas, como la morcheta, el digüeñe o el changle (que son unas especies muy consumidas acá).